# Long version of \edef, \xdef, \protected@edef

Tags: macros

What is the long version of `\edef`, `\xdef`, `\protected@edef` ... Do they work when we add a `\long` in front of them, like for `\def` :

```
\long\def\macom{...} 
\long\edef\macom{...} 
\long\gdef\macom{...} 
\long\xdef\macom{...} 
\long\protected@edef\macom{...}
```

Comment: The last one won't work (the `\long` prefix would incorrectly apply itself to the first token of the definition of `\protected@edef` The definition of `\protected@edef` is only 5 lines, it would be easy to make a long version if it were needed, but it's never been needed so far:-) All the others are OK.

Comment: As written, none of the definitions really need to be long as there are no arguments. The only way this will show up is if you are doing an `\ifx` test against another long macro. What is the context?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\long` can go in front of `\def`, `\gdef`, `\edef` and `\xdef`, so the first four constructions work. However the expansion of `\protected@edef` is

```
\let\@@protect\protect
\let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
\afterassignment\restore@protect
\edef
```

so a `\long` in front of `\protected@edef` would give an error.

```
\def\protected@longedef{%
  \let\@@protect\protect
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \afterassignment\restore@protect
  \long\edef}
```

Why would you need this is not clear, but here it is.